# STDOUT & STDERR from previous Command as Arguments for next Command

Tags: bash, shell, variables, stdout, stderr

Somehow I don't find a sufficient answer to my problem, only parts of hackarounds.

I'm calling a single "chained" shell command (from a Node app), that starts a long-running update process, which it's stdout/-err should be handed over, as arguments, to the second part of the shell command  (another Node app that logs into a DB).

I'd like to do something like this:

```
updateCommand 2>$err 1>$out ; logDBCommand --log arg err out
```

- Can't use `>` as it is only for files or file descriptors.
- Also if I use shell variables (like `error=$( { updateCommand | sed 's/Output/tmp/'; } 2>&1 ); logDBCommand --log arg \"${error}.\"`), I can only have stdout or both mixed into one argument.
- And I don't want to pipe, as the second command (logCommand) should run whether the first one succeeded or failed execution.
- And I don't want to cache to file, cause honestly that's missing the point and introduce another asynchronous error vector
- List item

Comment: How would caching to file cause an asynchronous error?

Comment: With a pipe, both sides are run simultaneously, though either side might exit on SIGPIPE if one end closes, but if your `logCommand` handled that it gracefully, though it would still be tough to disentangle stdout and stderr with a pipe

Comment: @123, obviously ending one program with a file write and picking it up later is asynchronous and having an extra disk write is missing the point and isn't  the point (and could, not saying it will, make a problem worst case)

Comment: @EricRenouf, and that's exactly what I'd like to avoid, cause (I should clear up that it's embedded hardware) it is a typical "one calls the other with arguments" setup, and having both parallel (though having to gain through that) is an anti-pattern and a waste of resources (especially that the update command could take up a few hours to days, worst case).

But how would you write that? Maybe I'll get the solutions a little closer.

Comment: If `logCommand` is a bash script you could add something like `trap "done_flag=1" SIGPIPE` then within the rest of the script, just see if `done_flag` is set, so you know it's time to exit.

Comment: @ThaBrad That is synchronous, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean. Also you haven't explained how you think this will introduce errors.

Comment: @123, anyways, leave synchronousness out, it introduces another error vector with a disk read/write

Comment: @ThaBrad how does it?

Comment: @EricRenouf, nope, a Nodejs app

Comment: I'm not familiar with node.js, but perhaps it offers similar signal handling abilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little chat in [#!/bin/bash](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98569/bin-bash) someone suggested to just make use of tpmsf (file system held in RAM), which is the 2nd most elegant (but only possible) way to do this. So I can make use of the `>` operator and have `stdout` and `stderr` in separate variables in memory.

```
command1 >/dev/shm/c1stdout 2>/dev/shm/c1stderr 
A=$(cat /dev/shm/c1sdtout) 
B=$(cat /dev/shm/c1stderr) 
command2 $A $B
```

**(or shorter):**

```
A=$(command1 2>/dev/shm/c1stderr ) 
B=$(cat /dev/shm/c1stderr) 
command2 $A $B
```